# How do I re-enable Outlook Web Access on an Exchange 2003 Server after I accidentally removed IIS?

Tags: iis, exchange, exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

I accidentally removed IIS via Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> Add Or Remove Windows Components -> Application Server -> Internet Information Services (IIS).

I reinstalled IIS, and it remembered my standard (directory-based) web sites.

But Outlook Web Access is gone.

How can I re-enable Outlook Web Access without reinstalling Exchange 2003?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this first:

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=883380

And if that doesn't work, try this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320202

Comment: +1 for the great links.

Comment: Here's what worked for me:

1) Reinstalling Exchange Server 2003, then re-applying SP2.  Note that I did not have to remove Exchange; I just had to use the "Reinstall" option in the Setup program.  

2) In http://support.microsoft.com/?id=883380, I performed option 3, editing the metabase file directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have uninstalled IIS which had Exchange on it. You will need to reinstall Exchange and apply all its service packs and hotfixes to get it working again.

Sadly, there is no shortcut for the same.

Regards,
Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

The links in Joeqwerty's [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/79880/how-do-i-re-enable-outlook-web-access-on-an-exchange-2003-server-after-i-accident/79883#79883) are excellent.  The first link describes resetting the IIS virtual directories for OWA.  This might be worth a shot, since they don't look like they will take very long, but I would not be hopeful.   From the second link ..

> If you have to reinstall IIS on the
>   server that is also running Exchange
>   2000 Server or Exchange Server 2003,
>   you have to reinstall Exchange Server
>   at the same time.

**An alternative is to rebuild the server from a backup before the removal of IIS, then put back the current mailbox and public folder stores.**  Not sure if this will be less work than re-install of Exchange, but I expect it is more likely to get all of the configuration details set properly.

I hope you learned something about taking proper care on production servers ...